# Why isn't my exception being caught?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

This is the stack trace I get:

```
[Fault] exception, information=Error: Directory id 3 already in use
at cantrips.assets.index::AssetIndex/dirIdChanged()[/home/luismasuelli/Proyectos/flash-assets-index-ritual/assets-index-loader/src/cantrips/assets/index/AssetIndex.as:72]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at cantrips.assets.index::AssetDirectory/set id()[/home/luismasuelli/Proyectos/flash-assets-index-ritual/assets-index-loader/src/cantrips/assets/index/AssetDirectory.as:68]
at Main/updateSelectedDirectory()[/home/luismasuelli/Proyectos/flash-assets-index-ritual/assets-index-editor/src/Main.mxml:192]
at Main/__dirUpdateCurrent_click()[/home/luismasuelli/Proyectos/flash-assets-index-ritual/assets-index-editor/src/Main.mxml:401]
```

This is the implementation of Main/updateSelectedDirectory():

```
    private function updateSelectedDirectory():void {
        try {
            var newId:uint = uint(dirId.text);
            var newName:String = StringUtil.trim(dirName.text);
            var selectedDirectory:AssetDirectory = assetBrowserTree.selectedItem as AssetDirectory;
            if (selectedDirectory) {
                selectedDirectory.id = newId;
                selectedDirectory.name = newName;
                assetBrowserTree.expandItem(selectedDirectory.parent, false);
                assetBrowserTree.expandItem(selectedDirectory.parent, true);
            }
        } catch (error:Error) {
            Alert.show(error.message, "Cannot update");
        }
    }
```

Why is not the exception being caught by `try {} catch(error:Error) {}`?.

The exception is an exception created by me, with a well-understood scenario where it is triggered (I created the exception and designed those scenarios and I am testing them; exception is triggered as I expect). I also tried using the exact name of the exception (AssetIndexError) in the catch block, and no confusion or ambiguous name exists (this means: there's no another AssetIndexError class declared elsewhere I could be importing instead of this).

Explanation:

- cantrips.assets.index is code I have control over.
- Main/* is the main window. I also have control over that code.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your error seems to be tied to an event handler, so likely it's thrown after the block of code in your try/catch runs.

Comment: Yep I found something that's telling me what you said. Please expand it as an answer so I can accept it and take it for the future :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your stack, you'll see the error is not being thrown in the code shown (which is near the bottom of the stack), but here:

> `dirIdChanged` at **AssetIndex.as:72**

Further down in the stack you'll see the following:

> at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()

This means that stack was asynchronous in between `AssetDirectory.set id()` and 
`AssetIndex.dirIdChanged()`

When you add an event handler, all code in the current block will usually run prior to the event handler code (as they are not in the same thread).

So in this case, all your code in the `try/catch` will have run before the event handler's code - which is why the error is not being caught.

Any time you are handling an event, you will need to have another try/catch, or use an asynchronous error handling technique.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a complement the OP made to the accepted answer.*

The main reason of this trouble is that I did not understand how the event flow is done.

The event flow is asynchronous, and I thought as it being synchronous. If the event flow was synchronous, it is not hard to think that what I intended was right: The exception could be thrown in the same execution stack and everything would be fine (i.e. a method calls another method, such method calls a third method, blah blah blah exception and explosion).

When the event flow is asynchronous as ActionScript flow is, the exception will be triggered in another execution stack, **but somehow the information provided is misleading as it should as if the execution stack was the same**.

The solution I implemented: A dumb object (i.e. a dumb new class) which acted like EventDispatcher but being synchronous: .dispatch() would not *post* an event execution to the event flow, but instead execute by itself the registered event handlers, as a loop over the handlers, and calling each handler by hand, without the possibility of having stuff like `event.target` populated in the handlers.

Althought this design could be seen as bad from many points of view I would agree with, in this case it fit my needs of handlers throwing exceptions and code executed synchronously.